# For loop is not giving expected output using pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to write a bill program where i want the cgst, sgst from the bill as output. All was going fine but i got stuck on a problem. I want separate names of product from the result of dataframe's output but i am getting only the name of only one product but the amount was sum of two...

**Here's my code:**

```
import pandas as pd
count = 0

num = int(input("Type number of items: "))
while count < num:
    count += 1
    print("-----------------------")
    item = input("Enter Item Name: ")
    SP = int(input("enter selling price of " + item + ": "))
    gstrate = float(input("Enter GST rate: "))
    cgst = SP * ((gstrate/2)/100)
    sgst = cgst
    amount = SP + cgst + sgst

    data = pd.DataFrame({
        'Item ': [item],
        'Price': [SP],
        'CGST': [cgst],
        'SGST': [sgst],
        'Amount payable': [amount],
    })

print(data)
```

**what i am getting is this example output:**

````
    Type number of items: 2
    -----------------------
    Enter Item Name: samsung
    enter selling price of samsung: 2341
    Enter GST rate: 34
    -----------------------
    Enter Item Name: iphone
    enter selling price of iphone: 1234567
    Enter GST rate: 15
        Item     Price       CGST       SGST  Amount payable
    0  iphone  1234567  92592.525  92592.525      1419752.05
    ```
````

**What i want the output to be:**

```
    Type number of items: 2
    -----------------------
    Enter Item Name: iphone
    enter selling price of iphone: 1000
    Enter GST rate: 18
    -----------------------
    Enter Item Name: samsung
    enter selling price of samsung: 1000
    Enter GST rate: 18
          Item Price  CGST  SGST  Amount payable
    0   iphone  1000  90.0  90.0          1180.0
    1  samsung  1000  90.0  90.0          1180.0
```

As you can see, i am getting only name samsung not iphone and samsung saparatley

Comment: you create a new data frame on each iteration of your loop, so your data frame will only containt the last item entered

Comment: @Zephyrus No, It won't work. OP need to append to a dataframe.

Comment: Now tell me guys... I had made some changes. Please tell me now why it's happening?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle is correct. You overwrite `data` each time you run the loop, and then you only print `data` at the end. If you want all of the data in a single DataFrame, create the DataFrame once and then use the `append` method to append the new data each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each iteration of your loop you are creating a new data frame with only this loops data and overwitting any data that was in the last data frame. So when you finish your loops and print the dataframe all thats in it is the data from the last iteration of the loop since you created a new dataframe on each iteration.

Instead you could create the data frame before the loop and then just append to the data frame on each iteration of the loop

```py
import pandas as pd
items = []
columns = ['Item', 'Price', 'CGST', 'SGST', 'Amount payable']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
num = int(input("Type number of items: "))

for _ in range(num):
    print("-----------------------")
    item = input("Enter Item Name: ")
    SP = int(input("enter selling price of " + item + ": "))
    gstrate = float(input("Enter GST rate: "))
    cgst = SP * ((gstrate/2)/100)
    sgst = cgst
    amount = SP + cgst + sgst
    data = [item, SP, cgst, sgst, amount]
    df_row = dict(zip(columns, data))
    df = df.append(df_row, ignore_index=True)

print(df)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Type number of items: 2
-----------------------
Enter Item Name: iphone
enter selling price of iphone: 1000
Enter GST rate: 18
-----------------------
Enter Item Name: samsung
enter selling price of samsung: 1000
Enter GST rate: 18
      Item Price  CGST  SGST  Amount payable
0   iphone  1000  90.0  90.0          1180.0
1  samsung  1000  90.0  90.0          1180.0
```